# How to pass both the function result and the string calling it, to a function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a function plog() which logs both the function and the output of said function to save me typing the full logging command each time.

```
>>> #! python
...
>>> import logging
>>>
>>> def plog(output, command):
...     logging.debug('{} enumerates as {}'.format(str(command), str(output)))
...
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
...                     format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
>>> plog(type(True), 'type(True)')
2019-04-28 14:40:01,154 - DEBUG - type(True) enumerates as <class 'bool'>
```

However it seems silly to be repeating myself when calling plog - is there a way that I can basically be calling:

```
>>> plog(type(True))
```

And receive the same output?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Tomothy32 using eval() is not the greatest solution.
Instead of using eval(), you could do something like that:

```
def plog(command, *args):
    method_call_str = "{}({})".format(command.__name__  ,", ".join(str(a) for a in args));
    logging.debug("{} enumerates to {}".format(method_call_str , command(*args)))
```

you would need to change your method call to for example this:

```
plog(max, 1, 2)
```

this would result in : `max(1, 2) enumerates to 2`

Answer (score -1):

You could use the eval() command to execute the string passed to the method:

`def plog(command):
    logging.debug('{} enumerates as {}'.format(command, eval(command)))`

You could then pass the code that should executed as a string to the method:

`plog("type(True)")`

Comment: You really should not be using `eval`, especially in this context. It allows the user to execute arbitrary code that could be malicious. At the very least, mention that it is unsafe.

Comment: Yes i totally agree, but when the input to the function is always declared by the programmer, there wont be any security issue

Comment: Security issues aside, `eval` is slow and makes debugging extremely difficult.

Comment: Okay, i see your point, but what would be an alternative in this specific case?

Comment: So this does seem to work for my use case (thanks @jakob-em) but how does eval make debugging difficult?

Comment: This is something that shouldn't be done; there is always a better way. For example, a REPL should be used. Without knowing the exact context of where OP needs this kind of function in real-life code, I can't suggest a different alternative.

Comment: @scon The tracebacks will be super unhelpful, something like `<string> in <module>`.